# Laravel 4 Uploading file

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with uploading files on laravel 4
here's the code

```
        $file = Input::file('file');
        $path = 'public/image';
        $filename = Str::random(20) .'.'. File::extension(Input::file('logo.name'));

        $file->move('public/image',$file->getClientOriginalName());

        return Redirect::back();
```

When I run the code,I got error notice Call to a member function move().what's wrong with the code?

Comment: Have you confirmed that there definitely is a file with that name?  Perhaps you need `Input::file('logo')` instead of `'file'`?

Comment: Try to check with `if (Input::hasFile('file')) {}` if there is an uploaded file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to follow these steps -

1. Better to try to do some crosscheck before trying to upload the attachment.

   For Example:

   `Public static function has_file($key)
   {
       return ! is_null(static::file("{$key}.tmp_name")); 
   }`
2. Try to give permission to the corresponding folder.
3. Check your path what you have given correctly.

Comment: I should add the has_file to validate the file,it worked thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

You could debug by var_dump($_FILES). I had a problem with uploads because I forgot to open my form with files set to true. Below is the example from the laravel docs

echo Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar', 'files' => true))